# Bash shell scripting: replace n bytes in a specific position in every line of a large files with spaces

Tags: bash

I have a large file with positional data. I know that in every line, from position 829 to 1084, there are characters not recognized and not correctly interpreted by the editors (eg characters interpreted as new line).

I want to replace these characters with spaces in each line of the file. In java I can get the desired result by reading the file by byte, however I cannot replicate the behavior via shell command

Thank you all!

Comment: Can you specify the problematic characters (for instance by posting a hexdump of the relevant part)? You said they are interpreted as new line. Are they actual new lines?

Comment: Problematic characters are control character that are not well interpreted by editor :-( Those characters are in a specific position on each line of the file: if i read the file byte by byte, i can found them exactly from 829 to 1084 character, if read each line as a string, those character are interpreted and the line result cutted

Comment: That didn't answer my answer but just repeated what was already in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A foolproof (albeit a bit inefficient) way of working with arbitrary bytes in regular shell utils: Hexdump the input, transform the hexdump, convert the hexdump back.

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
dump() { od -tx1 -vAn "$@" | tr -d \\n; }
undump() { xxd -r -p "$@"; }
rep=$(printf %256s | dump)
dump infile | sed -E "s/((^| 0a)( ..){828})( ..){256}/\1$rep/g" | undump > outfile
```

Above script works under two assumptions

- Each "line" to be replaced has at least 1084 characters.
- In your question, the indices in *"`from 829 to 1084`"* are both 1-based and inclusive.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and for your help! Unfortunately, some characters are interpreted as new line and, in addiction, each line to be replaced has more than 1084 characters (1500) :-( I think that the solution is to find something that give you the possibility to elab the file for bytes

Comment: *"`each line to be replaced has more than 1084 characters`"* Consider yourself lucky – It's not a problem but a requirement to use this command. I edited the command to work with arbitrary bytes.

Comment: THANK YOU very much! Now it works!!!! Exactly what I was looking for!!!! Thank you again, you save my weekend :-)